# How I can fix it

Tags: html, css, visual-studio, web, webkit

```
@-webkit-keyframes slide_animation{
    0% {left:0px;}
    10% {left:0px;}
    20% {left: 1200px;}
    30% {left: 1200px;}
    40% {left: 2400px;}
    50% {left: 2400px;}
    60% {left: 1200px;}
    70% {left: 1200px;}
    80% {left: 0px;}
    90% {left: 0px;}
    100% {left: 0px;}
}
```

Always define standard rule '@keyframes' when defining keyframes.css(vendorPrefix)

Comment: What is it that needs fixing? And note that not all browsers will interpret the -webkit- prefix so put a keyframes definitiion without it as well (or, instead of will do for most nowadays). caniuse.com is a useful site for checking whether you need to use such prefixes.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to define the classic CSS `keyframe` before

```
@keyframes slide_animation {
  0% { left: 0px; }
  10% { left: 0px; }
  20% { left: 1200px; }
  30% { left: 1200px; }
  40% { left: 2400px; }
  50% { left: 2400px; }
  60% { left: 1200px; }
  70% { left: 1200px; }
  80% { left: 0px; }
  90% { left: 0px; }
  100% { left: 0px; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide_animation {
  0% { left: 0px; }
  10% { left: 0px; }
  20% { left: 1200px; }
  30% { left: 1200px; }
  40% { left: 2400px; }
  50% { left: 2400px; }
  60% { left: 1200px; }
  70% { left: 1200px; }
  80% { left: 0px; }
  90% { left: 0px; }
  100% { left: 0px; }
}
```